Uploading files using Elysiajs and save it to mongodb
I'm new to elysiajs and trying to upload files using multer and elysia, but its not working for me
i tried to add a beforehandle and afterhandle but it's still not working ,
.......................................................................
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads/",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 1000000 }, // Limit file size to 1MB
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).single("myFile"); // 'myFile' is the name of the file input field in the HTML form

// Check file type
function checkFileType(file: any, cb: any) {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Error: Images Only!");
  }
}

export const users = new Elysia({ prefix: "/files" })
  // .post("/s", upload);
  .guard(
    {
      beforeHandle() {
        upload;
      },
    },
    (users) =>
      users
        .post("/s", (req: any, res: any) => filesUpload(req, res))
        .get("/ss", () => "f")
  );


Help me to answer it, actually when you're using Elysiajs and Bun. Bun had a built-in function to do some upload files without external plugins like multer.
For Example in route you can implement like this which can handle you,
app.post(
        "/",
        async ({
          body,
        }: {
          body: {
            logo: File;
            fileVerification: File;
            data: string;
          };
        }) => {
          return RegisteredVillageController.addVillages({ body });
        },
        {
          tags: ["Registered_Village"],
          body: t.Object({
            logo: t.File({ description: "logo" }),
            fileVerification: t.File({ description: "fileVerification" }),
            data: t.String(),
          }),
          type: "formdata",
          required: ["file", "fileVerification", "data"],
        }
      );

Then inside the controller you can add Bun.write to write your file inside bun. In this sample, for naming file i used nanoid which you can install it first.
addVillages: async ({
    body,
  }: {
    body: {
      logo: File;
      fileVerification: File;
      data: string;
    };
  }) => {
    try {
      const file = body.logo;
      const fileVerification = body.fileVerification;
      const data = JSON.parse(body.data) as PropsVillage;

      if (!file.type.includes("image")) {
        return {
          data: [],
          message: "Unsupported Format File",
        };
      }
      if (!fileVerification.type.includes("pdf")) {
        return {
          data: [],
          message: "Unsupported Format File Verification",
        };
      }
      // file
      const ext = file.type === "image/jpeg" ? ".jpg" : ".png";
      const baseDir = "files/logo/";
      const newFileName = `${baseDir}${nanoid.nanoid()}${ext}`;
      await Bun.write(newFileName, file);

      const baseDirPdf = "files/pdf/";
      const newPdfName = `${baseDirPdf}${nanoid.nanoid()}.pdf`;
      await Bun.write(newPdfName, file);
      
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(" ~ addVillages: ~ error:", error);
      return {
        data: [],
        message: error.message,
      };
    }
  },

